# AttributeError: Computing the distance between two points

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am doing an exercise in the textbook Think Python by Allen Downey. I am sure that the code is correct but it keeps showing the same problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ADMIN/PycharmProjects/ProgrammingFundamental101/EXTRA EFFORTS/Classes_and_Objects.py", line 80, in <module>
    print(distance_between_points(blank.x, blank.y))
  File "C:/Users/ADMIN/PycharmProjects/ProgrammingFundamental101/EXTRA EFFORTS/Classes_and_Objects.py", line 74, in distance_between_points
    dx = p1.x - p2.x
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The code is below:

```
def distance_between_points(p1, p2):
    dx = p1.x - p2.x
    dy = p1.y - p2.y
    dist = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
    return dist

print(distance_between_points(blank.x, blank.y))
```

Both points blank.x and blank.y have been defined and assigned with values of 3 and 4.

What is going wrong with the arguments or the parameter?

Answer (score 2):

thanks so much for your effort and time.

After reviewing your suggestions and taking another look through the material. I figured it out.

I created two different points to be used as arguments and it worked!

```
b = Point()
b.x = 0
b.y = 0

g = Point()
g.x = 3
g.y = 4

print('distance', distance_between_points(b, g))

distance 5.0
```

Again, thanks so much for such prompt responses!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the code cannot be correct. Otherwise it would not throw an error. :) The error message tells you, what is wrong. In this line:

```py
dx = p1.x - p2.x
```

You are accessing the `x` property of `p1` and of `p2`. At least one of those two  (though I am guessing both) is a `float` type object, which does not have an attribute named `x`.

Unfortunately, you did not post the context, i.e. where `blank` comes from. So I can only guess that it is some sort of object representing a point in 2D-space, which has an `x` and a `y` attribute representing the point's coordinates as floats. I would assume that the `distance_between_points` function expects the arguments to be instances of that same point class. And instead (again, I am just guessing here) you are passing the `x`-coordinate of a point as the first and the `y`-coordinate as the second argument to the function instead of two different point objects.

If you post the entire relevant context (where `blank` comes from), we could verify this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `blank` is a `Point` object.

The function is expecting `p1` and `p2` to be `Point` objects. This means that what is needed is

```py
distance_between_points(some_point, another_point)
```

If python sees `some_point.x` it is no longer a `Point` object, it's the x coordinate of that `some_point` object.

In the code `p1` is `blank.x`, which means when it does `p1.x` it is doing `blank.x.x`, which is why python raises that error.